# Call a JavaScript function inside tag attribute

Tags: javascript, html

How can we call an JavaScript function inside tag attribute ?

```js
let imageURL = () => 'http://www.example.com/image.png';
```

```html
<img alt="error" src="javascript:imageURL()">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`src` accepts only url, you can place your function here: `<img alt="Not available" src="whatever" onload="this.onload=null; this.src=imageURL();"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript to change the image `src` attribute:

```js
document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'https://media.wired.com/photos/5b8999943667562d3024c321/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/trash2-01.jpg';
```

```html
<img alt="Not available" id="myImage" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not run js function on attribute, try this function
first it try to load placeholder, after placeholder loaded it then trigger JS function

```
<img src="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/RapidRadiantBug-small.gif" onload="this.onload=null; this.src=imageURL();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to change image source, see my example :

```js
document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', 'https://media.wired.com/photos/5b8999943667562d3024c321/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/trash2-01.jpg');
```

```html
<img alt="Not available" src="" id="image">
```